# How can I send an image from a QLabel, store it in a variable and then save it in a Postgresql column?

Tags: python, postgresql, pyqt, store

Good morning, I am developing a customer registration program using Python, using PyQT, I have been able to develop the possibility of selecting the images in a QLabel for the user to see, but I have tried many ways to save it in a variable and then send it to my database. Does anyone know of a better method to do it?

I attach the code that I have regarding the sending of this image, but it has resulted in a type error "can't adapt type 'QByteArray' <class 'psycopg2.ProgrammingError'>":

> imagen = self.labelImagen.pixmap() bArray = QByteArray()
> bufer = QBuffer(bArray)
> bufer.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
> bufer.close()
> imagen.save(bufer, "PNG")

Comment: Please don't create a new post that is almost the same as an [existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71210575/2001654) you created early. Also, the solution has been already provided in comments to that question. If there's something that's not clear, add a comment there. Please review the [tour], read [ask] and also the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Qt's database interfaces instead of psycopg2, but if you're already using that and want to keep using it, it'd be something like this:

```
imagen = self.labelImagen.pixmap()
bArray = QByteArray()
bufer = QBuffer(bArray)
bufer.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly) 
imagen.save(bufer, "PNG")

byte_data = bArray.data()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO yourTable(columnOfbyteaType) VALUES(%s)",
            psycopg2.Binary(byte_data))
```